# Generating time stamps from directory name

Tags: python

I have a list of directoaries and I would like to generate a time stamp each 15 minutes.
For example I have the Directoary name 2018-08-21 till 2018-10-20, but there are directories that doesn't exist in between. I want to handle that case.

Also I want to list the names of the timestamps as peakdata_timestamp.

I tried the following but it doesn't work as expected

```
for root, dirnames, files in os.walk(r"c:\ahmed\SpeedFT-meter1\peakdata"):
        for j in dirnames:
            for i in range(360):
                s = datetime.strptime(j, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(minutes=15)
                timeStamps.append(s)
                directoary_names.append(root + r'\'' + 'peakdata_' + s.strftime("%Y%m%d_%M%H"))
```

Comment: what is expected? what is the issue with the code snippet?

Comment: I get the time stamps but it's just 15minutes each time stamps, it doesn't increment each 15 minutes to the next minutes and hours

Comment: it's always in the format 2018-08-21 00:15:00

Comment: the 00:15:00 is always there, and the timestamps is not incremented at all

Comment: You are passing the argument as the name of the file. what if all the dirs have same dates then the difference will always be the same. Also,the default time for a date object will be 00:00:00 and if we add 15 to it it will always be 00:15:00 in that case it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I have added manually a counter to it and that fixed the problem

```
 hours_counter = 0
    minutes_counter = 0
    for root, dirnames, files in os.walk(r"c:\ahmed\SpeedFT-meter1\peakdata"):
        for j in dirnames:
            for i in range(360):

                minutes_counter = minutes_counter + 15
                if minutes_counter == 45:
                    minutes_counter = 0
                    hours_counter = hours_counter + 1
                s = datetime.strptime(j, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(hours= hours_counter, minutes=minutes_counter)
                timeStamps.append(s)
                directoary_names.append(root + r'\'' + 'peakdata_' + s.strftime("%Y%m%d_%M%H"))
```